# Why does pass-by-value parameters often make code optimization easier for the compiler?

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, pass-by-value

I am learning both C++ and OpenCV in parallel. I am reading the following that is a bit unclear why pass-by-value parameters often makes code optimization easier for the compiler.

> As a last note, you might have been surprised by the fact that our image modifying
>   function uses a pass-by-value image parameter. This works
>   because when images are copied, they still share the same image data.
>   So, you do not necessarily have to transmit images by references when
>   you want to modify their content. Incidentally, pass-by-value parameters
>   often make code optimization easier for the compiler.

```
void salt(Mat image, int n)
{
    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randomRow(0, image.rows - 1);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randomCol(0, image.cols - 1);

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        int i = randomCol(generator);
        int j = randomRow(generator);

        if (image.type() == CV_8UC1)
            image.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
        else if (image.type() == CV_8UC3)
            image.at<Vec3b>(j, i) = Vec3b(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825040/passing-by-value-and-copy-elision-optimization) will answer part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two words: **alias analysis**.  Remember that (for example) `const int &r` does not declare `r` to be a reference to an *unchanging* integer but a reference to an integer that may not be *used* to change it.  So any time that a write to *any* `int` *might* be to `r`’s referent, the value of `r` must be reloaded, and common subexpression elimination and code motion cannot occur.  If `r` is a local `int` **object**, the compiler can often prove that its address never escapes; then it can ignore any write to anything else, often allowing `r` to stay in a register or be discarded early.

This was given as an aside in the passage you quoted because it is less important in the case in question: `Mat` must contain a pointer to the underlying image data, so some aliasing is possible even when a `Mat` is passed by value.  (Being able to prove things about the pointer itself may give some benefit, but that must be set against the expense of reference counting or similar.)